# Clicking on span element does nothing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Writing a chrome extension to add translation to each word

However, the translation dynamically appears if you click on the word hence I'm trying to click on the word (which isn't doing anything)

Example what I need to click on:
`<span class="w" id="w2" xpath="1">iuvenis</span>`

What I got:

```js
const words = document.getElementById('rdlat').children;
    for (let word of words){
       if (word.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'span' && word.id != 'ln0')
       {
         word.dispatchEvent(new Event('click')); //have tried .click() and Event mouse down, mouse up
         observer.observe(document.querySelector('body'), config);
         translation = document.getElementsByClassName('btmpanel');
         console.log(translation);
         word.innerHTML = word.innerHTML + '(' + translation + ')';
       }
    }
```

No error, doesn't make the box appear

Page in question: https://www.cla.cambridgescp.com/files/cscp/cla/cla/exp/cla.html?fn=saga_132_1

Comment: `translation = document.getElementsByClassName('btmpanel');` <-- HTML collection  `'(' + translation + ')'` <-- using html collection as a string?

Comment: unsure what you are expecting `observer.observe` to be doing.

Comment: @epascarello You're right lol.  I had a .children[1].innerHTML but took it out while I was figuring out what went wrong

Comment: @epascarello it's a timeout until the element appears that i didn't include in the snippet